# Does not turn on my led strip ws2812, bluetooth, arduino UNO

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-uno

I am trying to make the functionality of emitting a color from a ws2812 LED strip from an hc-05 bluetooth module with an Arduino UNO, what happens is that the Arduino IDE program says that the code has no errors and sends it normally, and at the time of sending parameter 1 does not turn on:

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

int PIN = 6;
int NUMPIXELS = 8;

Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels = Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
SoftwareSerial miBT(10, 11);

char dato = 0;

void setup(){  
  miBT.begin(38400);
  pixels.begin();
  pixels.show();
}

void loop(){
  if(miBT.available()){
    dato = miBT.read();

    if(dato == '1'){
      pixels.setPixelColor(4,0,0,255);
      pixels.show();
      }else if(dato == '2'){
        pixels.setPixelColor(4,255,0,0);
        pixels.show();
        }
    }  
  }
```

I already tried to adjust again the pin through which it sends the color signal, test the led strip separately without the bluetooth module (If it works), I hope you can help me, I have to deliver next Monday

Comment: Have you tested that your ardunio actually receives a '1'?

Comment: Yes, I have the arduino in slave

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code then :(

Comment: Can you post a circuit diagram ?